# Include picture in result, JAX-RS, any performance penalty?

Tags: performance, jax-rs

As someone on this forum pointed out that send back picture is a bad idea since it have some performance issue. Thus he/she suggest to send back picture's url instead. I'm wondering how could sending back picture have performance impact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the picture is rather large, it will take up considerable bandwidth, and also slow down the rest of the JAX-RS framework. Let the client do the work of retrieving the image, it is their bandwidth after all.

If the pictures are hosted elsewhere (on another server), why hog up your bandwidth sending them. After all, while your server is handling hundreds of concurrent requests, each sending a photo, the client only needs to make a few request.

No matter where the pictures are hosted (as long as they are not hosted via JAX-RS), you are putting load on JAX-RS. Other requests will serve slowly because different threads are each trying to send a large file. Overall, this will make your application considerably slower.

Comment: @YH.Liang if the answer helped you, please mark it as Accpeted by clicking the check mark to its left ✅, so the community can benefit from it too